# If string contains two characters

Tags: php, string

I have looked everywhere for something like this.  I can't see to get it to work.
I'm trying to have a if statement if a string contains a colon AND a dash.

String example (true): "Visor - Color : Black"
String example (false): "Water Bottle - Blue"

I have tried different variations of this but its still not working.

```
if (preg_match(':|-]*', $productName)) {
    TRUE
} else {
    FALSE
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: To start with, your regexp needs delimiters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without regex:

```
if (substr_count($productName, '-') === 1 && substr_count($productName, ':') === 1) {
    // true
}
```